# Como definir rotas no Laravel que funcionem somente em ambiente de desenvolvimento?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Eu gostaria de saber como posso definir rotas no Laravel que funcionem somente em ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Creio que isso possa ser útil para facilitar os `debugs`.

Quero poder separar algumas rotas para utilizar apenas quando estiver em desenvolvimento e, em produção, essas rotas não existirem.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Laravel, é possível detectar se o ambiente em que o sistema está rodando em produção ou local.

## O arquivo app/start/local.php

No caso do desenvolvimento local, temos o arquivo chamado `app/start/local.php`, que só é adicionado à aplicação `Laravel 4` caso seja detectado que o `environment`(ambiente) esteja marcado como `"local"`.

Seria possível definir ali algumas rotas e, assim, elas funcionariam apenas quando a aplicação estivesse em desenvolvimento.

Um exemplo:

```
#app/start/local.php

Route::group(['prefix' => 'local'], function ()
{

    Route::get('login/{id}', function ($id)
    {
        $u = Usuario::findOrFail($id);

        Auth::login($u);

        return Redirect::to('/');
    });
});
```

Nesse caso, ao acessarmos a rota `localhost/local/login/1`, poderíamos autenticar um usuário de maneira simples, sem a necessidade de um formulário. E isso é algo muito útil para o desenvolvimento se tornar mais ágil.

## Métodos para detecção de ambiente de desenvolvimento

Se há a necessidade de saber em algum trecho de código que estamos ou não em ambiente de desenvolvimento, temos três formas de detectar isso, através de métodos presentes em `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`.

**Exemplo 1**:

```
var_dump(App::isLocal()); //bool(true);

var_dump(App::environment('local')); // bool(true)

var_dump(App::environment() === 'local')); // bool(true)
```

Não sei se depende da versão do `Laravel 4`, mas particularmente gosto de usar a primeira.

Com isso, é possível fazer o `include` de funções para debug, por exemplo, quando estamos em desenvolvimento.

Exemplo:

```
#app/start/global.php

if (App::isLocal()) 
    require app_path('local_functions.php');
```

## Detectando o ambiente através do host utilizado

Também é possível definir se a aplicação está em ambiente local ou não simplesmente verificando a `url` de origem da mesma.

A maneira que sempre costumo utilizar é adicionando algumas linhas de código ao arquivo `bootstrap/start.php`.

Assim:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() use($app) {

    $enviromentsHosts = [
        'localhost',
        'url_virtualhost',

    ];

    if (in_array($app['request']->getHost(), $enviromentsHosts)) {

        return 'local';

    } else {

        return 'production';
    }
});
```