# Como faço para usar a mesma configuração de app/config/local/database.php quando eu estiver rodando em enviroment "testing"?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

No `Laravel 4`, temos três tipos de ambientes que podem ser definidos: `local`, `production` e `testing`.

Inclusive publiquei algo referente a configuração do ambiente `local` aqui em : [Como definir rotas no Laravel que funcionem somente em ambiente de desenvolvimento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83934/como-definir-rotas-no-laravel-que-funcionem-somente-em-ambiente-de-desenvolvimen)

Gosto muito de usar a configuração acima para definir os dados do banco de dados local, e já deixar a configuração de produção pronta, para na hora de subir o arquivo, não ter que mexer em nenhuma configuração.

Porém, quando eu rodo os testes do `phpunit` (que invocaria o ambiente de `testing` do `Laravel 4`), as configurações do banco de dados utilizadas tem sido as do `production`.

Eu sei que tem uma pasta chamada `app/config/testing`, onde também posso adicionar o `database.php`, porém não gostaria de ficar "copiando e colando" as configurações do banco `local` para colocar no de `testing`, mas apenas usar a mesma configuração.

Qual é a melhor forma de fazer isso no `Laravel 4`?

Answer (score 1):

A princípio, existe uma gambiarra que pode ser feita.

Você pode criar um arquivo chamado `app/config/testing/database.php` e, ao "copiar e colar" a configuração de `app/config/local/database.php`, você pode simplesmente usar a função `include`.

```
return include_once __DIR__  . '/../local/database.php';
```

Outra maneira é fazer com que a aplicação reconheça que você está no ambiente `local`, quando estiver rodando em `testing`.

No arquivo `bootstrap/start.php`, existe um trecho onde o valor do ambiente atual é definido na variável `$env`.

Então, se seu código tiver algo parecido com isso:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(/** **/));
```

Faça assim:

```
  $env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(/** **/));

  if ($env === 'testing') $env = 'local';
```